# How to store values in a vector inside a while loop in R

Tags: r, vector, while-loop

For the next exercise: *From a certain numerical value, check if this is a natural number or not so that, if it is, it shows the divisors of this number and, if it is not, it shows an error message.*

As there was no predefined function for this I wrote:

```
n <- 102
x <- n
res <- c()

while (x>0){
  if (n%%x == 0){
    res[x] <- x
    x =  x-1
  } else {
    x = x -1
  } print("The values are ", res)
}

res
```

Works nice, except it´s not storing the values inside the vector. Any ideas?

I´m new to programming and stackoverflow. I hope this question is right posted and presented.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a counter "i" to save the value in the next entry of the vector

```
n <- 102
x <- n
res <- c()
i<-1
while (x>0){
  if (n%%x == 0){
    res[i] <- x
    x =  x-1
    i<-i+1
  } else {
    x = x -1

  }

}

res
```